# Permissions error trying to create local web dev environment in home folder

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

Hi I've been trying to create a local web dev environment in my home folder. My local LAMP is running fine, and I tried this tutorial to develop without the hassle of the permissions in var/www 
http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2012/10/how-to-enable-and-configure-apache2-userdir-module-in-ubuntu-server-12-04.html

I'm getting a 403 forbidden error when trying to access it like so:

```
http://localhost/~asdf/
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically the best place to put your web files is in /var/www//... But, if you create a virtual host in your machine and put some IP in /etc/hosts/ to point some "name". You can do that.

Virtual hosts:

```
cp -p /etc/apache/sites-avaliable/000-default.conf /etc/apache/sites-avaliable/myname.conf

sudo nano /etc/apache/sites-avaliable/myname.conf
```

edit the line:

```
serverName myname  

<Directory /var/www/myname/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Save it, and run:

```
sudo a2ensite myname.conf  
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Give some ip:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1     myname
```

Save it and now go to browser:

```
http://myname/
```

Now it's ok! :)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also found an in-depth tut on it here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Oh, and I think your 000-default.conf should be just "default". 000-default.conf is a link to default in sites-enabled.

Comment: Yes, you are correcte. But depende on system... some is 000-default.conf and other may be is default. I'm glad i can help you out.